# Get property value from another object using Reflection.Emit

Tags: .net, reflection.emit

This is my first foray into using Reflection.Emit.  I'm dynamically building a proxy for a provided object.  The proxy passes any **public** property accesses through to the provided object.  The error I'm receiving is:

> Property accessor 'AccessorName' on object 'ProxyObject' threw the following exception:
>   Attempt by method 'ProxyObject.get_AccessorName()' to access method
>   'NS.CoreObject.get_AccessorName() failed.

From what I can assume and gather, this would be due to the automatically-generated property getter method being private and hidden.  But how do I work around this using a `MethodBuilder`?

According to the post at [Create DynamicMethod to assign value to a property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588175/create-dynamicmethod-to-assign-value-to-a-property), you can do it with a DynamicMethod by declaring the method to be "associated" with the target module, but I need to build a full class.  Is there an equivalent "association" that can be achieved through Reflection.Emit?

This is a basic operation I'm trying to perform, so I'm certain that it's something straight-forward and simple that I'm unaware of.

Comment: That's MethodAccessException.  It sure sounds like the property is not in fact public.  Make this work in C# first, the IL you get from it will be very helpful in your emit code as well.

Comment: Of course, a public property means nothing when your class is not public.  In my head, this type was being defined within the same module.  Yet another *"I wasted hours on this?"* moment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `MethodBuilder`: you cannot. You are subject to the usual rules of accessibility. You can, however, cheat via `DynamicMethod`, which allows you to pretend (if you have enough access) that the method you are creating is actually a static method *of a given type* (or a given module, etc). This means you *can* freely access private state, for example:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

public class Foo
{
    public Foo(int bar)
    {
        Bar = bar;
    }
    private int Bar { get; set; }
}
static class Program {
    static void Main()
    {
        var method = new DynamicMethod("cheat", typeof(int),
            new[] { typeof(object) }, typeof(Foo), true);
        var il = method.GetILGenerator();
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Castclass, typeof(Foo));
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, typeof(Foo).GetProperty("Bar",
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic
            ).GetGetMethod(true));
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        var func = (Func<object, int>)method.CreateDelegate(
            typeof(Func<object, int>));

        var obj = new Foo(123);
        Console.WriteLine(func(obj));
    }
}
```

If you are *only* obtaining the value of the property, it should also be noted that `Delegate.CreateDelegate` can do the same automatically, via the getter method:

```
var method = typeof(Foo).GetProperty("Bar",
    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .GetGetMethod(true);
var func = (Func<Foo, int>)
    Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<Foo, int>), method);
```

Comment: Makes sense (and is creative, too).  If I'm building up a type via TypeBuilder, am I able to get the IL generated by your answer into the TypeBuilder-built type?  Or are the two mutually exclusive?

Comment: @redman getting the same IL wouldn't help. TypeBuilder is *still* restricted to standard accessibility. At the IL level you can *ask* for just about **anything**: it will still be checked at first use.

Comment: I just realized that part of my question was ambiguous.  The properties I'm trying to access are *public*.  It's the automatically-generated accessors that are not.  (I've updated my question to reflect this.)  So with that consideration, is it easier to make use of a property of another object through MethodBuilder?

Comment: While the answer did not answer my intended question, it answered the perceived question based on an ambiguous framing.  For this, you must get the credit.  Now I at least know a trick for future use.

Comment: @redman if the property accessor is public, it should just work