# How to set property values for indexers using Expressions?

Tags: c#, reflection, expression

I am currently kind of stuck with setting a value into an indexer expression passed into the following function:

```cs
private static void SetPropertyValue<T, TValue>(this T target, Expression<Func<T, TValue>> memberLamda, TValue value)
{
    var memberSelectorExpression = memberLamda.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (memberSelectorExpression != null)
    {
        var property = memberSelectorExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;
        if (property != null)
        {
            property.SetValue(target, value, null);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I have the following class

```cs
class Entity 
{
    public object this[string name] 
    {
        get { /* */ }
        set { /* */ }
    }
}
```

When I now call the previous defined function with the following values I only get a reference to the backing `get_Item()` method:

```cs
var entity = new Entity();
// ...
SetPropertyValue(entity, x => x[memberName], value);
```

Does anybody have a hint for me, how to solve this issue? Any idea will help.

Many thanks to all of you...

Comment: I think this *might* (not sure) be related to one of my old questions: [Create dynamic method to assign value to a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588175/create-dynamicmethod-to-assign-value-to-a-property)

Comment: Do you expect `x[membername] = value` to be valid? What is `membername`? Think about what `x[membername]` means... what do the type arguments of `Func<>` represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see what you are attempting - a single `SetPropertyValue` extension that works for regular and indexed properties. In that case you need to determine the type of reference in the passed in `Expression` to determine how to call `SetValue`:

```
public static void SetPropertyValue<T, TValue>(this T target, Expression<Func<T,TValue>> memberFn, TValue value) {
    var b = memberFn.Body;
    if (b is MethodCallExpression bc && bc.Method.IsSpecialName && bc.Method.Name.StartsWith("get_")) {
        var PI = typeof(T).GetProperty(bc.Method.Name.Substring(4));
        PI.SetValue(target, value, bc.Arguments.Select(a => a.Evaluate<object>()).ToArray());
    }
    else if (b is MemberExpression bm) {
        var pi = bm.Member;
        pi.SetValue(target, value);
    }
}
```

You can determine the indexed property name a number of different ways, I decided to assume a special name beginning with `get_` would be followed by the indexed property name (the current C# compilers use `Item`) and use that to find the property. If the compiler changed the name pattern, (e.g. `Item_get`) I don't see any relationship between the `MethodInfo` of the `get` method and the property it represents, so you would have to re-write this code, but that is always a hazard of Reflection anyway. Perhaps looking for a property whose name is contained by the get method name would be slightly more robust, if slower.

Here is a version that does that:

```
public static void SetPropertyValue<T, TValue>(this T target, Expression<Func<T,TValue>> memberFn, TValue value) {
    var b = memberFn.Body;
    if (b is MethodCallExpression bc && bc.Method.IsSpecialName) {
        var PI = typeof(T).GetProperties().First(pi => bc.Method.Name.Contains(pi.Name));
        PI.SetValue(target, value, bc.Arguments.Select(a => a.Evaluate<object>()).ToArray());
    }
    else if (b is MemberExpression bm) {
        var pi = bm.Member;
        pi.SetValue(target, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is exactly the thing I want to achieve. I will try it and give feedback to you.#

Comment: Wow... thanks. It works pretty well. But I recognized, that this reflection logic is not really necessary because I had all the options in my hand to explicitly use a setter action, depending on the input. Therefor I also achieved a performance improvement not using reflection.

Comment: @MacX Excellent on avoiding reflection - always best to use non-reflection tools. I checked and it seems the C# specification specifies the name of the methods and property for an [Indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#class-members) so just using `Item` directly is probably safe.